# how to optimize this select where and "datetime" sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query, which was logged in mysql slow log file:

```
# Time: 2019-06-12T10:23:05.410474Z
# User@Host: coi[coi] @  [172.31.ip.ip]  Id:    91
# Query_time: 7.099090  Lock_time: 0.000065 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 
844952

use coi;
SET timestamp=1560334985;

SELECT  `trades`.* FROM `trades` 
    WHERE `trades`.`market_id` = 'omgeth' 
    AND (created_at > '2019-06-11 18:22:58.310183')  
    ORDER BY price 
    LIMIT 1;
```

Here , how to optimize this query? adding index to "market_id and created_at" column?

why this query checked 844952 records? what if I add index only to "created_at" column? will this help?

this is my table structure:

```
(this create table SQL comes from the "show create table" command) 

CREATE TABLE `trades` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` decimal(32,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `market_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_trades_on_created_at` (`created_at`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_trades_on_market_id` (`market_id`),
  KEY `index_trades_on_price` (`price`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3509954 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

thank a lot!

Comment: But questions about performance should include a table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE trades` and a `EXPLAIN query`

Comment: Short "answer": ideally you want the index `trades(market_id, created_at, price)`  to allow sorting [optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) on the index and remove "using filesort" and a possible temporary table.

Comment: You manually changed the create table statement it contains a error..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks a lot, I am trying your solution.

Comment: thank you so much ! it works ! I just added index to trades(market_id, created_at), and the query time reduced to 0.33 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM `trades` t
WHERE t.`market_id = 'omgeth' AND 
      t.created_at > '2019-06-11 18:22:58.310183'
ORDER BY t.price
LIMIT 1;
```

You want an index on `trades(market_id, created_at)`.

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 in this case i also consider the index `trades(market_id, price).` it will scan i little bit more records as the range created_at is removed but it will allow the order by index optimization..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you! I will try and let you know~